# failed installation of linter-eslint in atom

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I keep receiving this error in atom when I try to install the linter-eslint package;

```sh
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated sb-memoize@1.0.2: No longer maintained - Use lodash probably
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...7.0.0-alpha.16","babe'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kanji\.atom\.apm\_logs\2021-01-03T19_21_12_164Z-debug.log
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: please include the command that you are using for installing `linter-eslint`

Comment: I'm just trying to install it in atom through the package installer